# (standard_in) 1: parse error

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing a quick script for calculating individual interface throughput from data pulled from /proc/net/dev and I'm having an issue. It converts it from bytes to megabits.

This is working on my ubuntu server (3.2.0 kernel), however when I try and run this on older devices (2.6.18 era) it's not working. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
int1_byte_rx=`cat $logfile | grep $int1 | awk '{print $2}' | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'`
int1_byte_tx=`cat $logfile | grep $int1 | awk '{print $10}' | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'`
int1_rx_thrpt=$(echo "($int1_byte_rx * 0.00000762939453) / $iterations / ($time * 60)" | bc -l)
int1_tx_thrpt=$(echo "($int1_byte_tx * 0.00000762939453) / $iterations / ($time * 60)" | bc -l)
```

When I run this I get the following error (from debug mode):

```
int1_rx_thrpt=$(echo "($int1_byte_rx * 0.00000762939453) / $iterations / ($time * 60)" | bc -l)
echo "($int1_byte_rx * 0.00000762939453) / $iterations / ($time * 60)" | bc -l
++ echo '(1.13417e+10 * 0.00000762939453) / 57 / (5 * 60)'
++ bc -l
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
+ int1_rx_thrpt=
int1_tx_thrpt=$(echo "($int1_byte_tx * 0.00000762939453) / $iterations / ($time * 60)" | bc -l)
echo "($int1_byte_tx * 0.00000762939453) / $iterations / ($time * 60)" | bc -l
++ echo '(9.78048e+09 * 0.00000762939453) / 57 / (5 * 60)'
++ bc -l
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error
```

I've been able to trace the problem back to bc itself, however I'm not actually sure how to correct it.

Any advice is welcome.

Thanks for your time,

Comment: You can more easily reproduce this problem with `echo 1.13417e+10 | bc -l`. (Or running `bc -l` interactively and just typing in `1.13417e+10`.)

Comment: Indeed I can - thank you. From that info I can assume that it does not like scientific notation. Is there a specific mode that allows this? I was under the impression that mathlib allows this (it works on bc version 1.06.95 but not 1.06)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `/proc/net/dev` doesn't have large enough values to force `awk` to print any output in scientific notation, so I cannot *easily* test this, but here's my suggested fix:

```
int1_byte_rx=`cat $logfile | grep $int1 | awk '{print $2}' | awk '{sum+=$1} END {printf "%f", sum}'`
int1_byte_tx=`cat $logfile | grep $int1 | awk '{print $10}' | awk '{sum+=$1} END {printf "%f", sum}'`
```

(Note the `printf "%f",` portion near the end.)

The trick is to prevent `awk` from generating the scientific format in the first place.

Comment: That definitely did it. I suppose the newer version assumes %f to begin with. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: .. or, perhaps your newer systems haven't been up long enough to have enough packets to switch to scientific formatting. But check out Dennis's answer, it's nice.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need those long pipelines and you don't need to use `bc`.

```
int1_byte_rx=$(awk -v int="$int1" '$0 ~ int {sum += $2} END {print sum}' "$logfile")
int1_byte_tx=$(awk -v int="$int1" '$0 ~ int {sum += $10} END {print sum}' "$logfile")
int1_rx_thrpt=$(awk -v int1_byte_rx="$int1_byte_rx" -v iter="$iterations" -v time="$time" 'BEGIN {printf "%12.2f", (int1_byte_rx * 0.00000762939453) / iter / (time * 60)}')
int1_tx_thrpt=$(awk -v int1_byte_tx="$int1_byte_tx" -v iter="$iterations" -v time="$time" 'BEGIN {printf "%12.2f", (int1_byte_tx * 0.00000762939453) / iter / (time * 60)}')
```

You can combine the first two lines like this:

```
read -r int1_byte_rx int1_byte_tx <<< $(awk -v int="$int1" '$0 ~ int {sumrx += $2; sumtx+= $10} END {print sumrx, sumtx}' "$logfile")
```

and you'll only have to read the logfile once.

Another alternative would be to write the entire script in AWK or another language that supports floating point arithmetic such as Python or Perl.

Comment: @sarnold: Thank you. I appreciate the compliment.

Comment: Agreed :) I'll toy around with that tomorrow. Thanks!